# Pandas groupby drop_duplicates based on multiple conditions on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset like this:

```
ID    Data    AddType    Num
123   What    HA1        1
123   I       HA1        2
123   What    OT1        1
456   I       OT2        1
456   Gotta   OT2        2
```

With this, I need to group by the ID and keep the Data based on two rules for AddType and Num:

1. If there is one HA1 type row present, keep it
2. If there's no HA1 type row present, keep whichever row has the highest Num value
3. If there's multiple HA1 type rows present, keep the one with the highest Num value

So basically priority 1 is to have a HA1 type row. The seond priority (if there's multiple HA1 type rows or there's none), priority 2 is the Num value. So the desired outcome is:

```
ID    Data    AddType    Num
123   I       HA1        2
456   Gotta   OT2        2
```

I've tried a couple of variations with gropuby and drop_duplicates, but I can't seem to figure this out. How can I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `sort_values` then `drop_duplicates`

```
out = df.sort_values(by = 'AddType', key = lambda x : x.eq('HA1')).sort_values('Num').drop_duplicates('ID',keep='last')
Out[506]: 
    ID   Data AddType  Num
4  456  Gotta     OT2    2
1  123      I     HA1    2
```